# ReadStream push

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read that ReadStream#push methods returns false if inner buffer is full, and I did an experiment.

```js
   

 "use strict";

    var Readable = require("stream").Readable;
    var i = 0;

    class CountableStream extends Readable {
        constructor(options) {
            super(options);
        }

        _read() {
            if (i < 10) {
                i++;
                for (var k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
                    // highWaterMark is set to 3, while we push 3 objects here, 
                    var ret = this.push({test: i * k});
                    console.log(ret); //print "false" here, which means the internal buffer is full
                }

            } else {
                this.push(null);
            }
        }
    }

    // Set highWaterMark to 1 purposefully
    var s = new CountableStream({objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 1});
    s.on("data", function (data) {
//I can print all data without losing any
        console.log("!!" + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

As you may read from the code, I am pushing more elements at once more than the inner buffer can hold, but I can still print all without missing any of them.
Apparently the excessive data were truly pushed onto the buffer without throwing them away.

Then my doubt is

1. Is the "highWaterMask" just a hint to control speed and not a rigid restriction?
2. If the push method returns false, I guess I can invoke "this.pause()" to stop the stream temporarily, but how should I resume this flow again? Should I invoke the resume method in any event callback?

Thanks!

Comment: My observation is that back pressure signalling in node is normally advisory only. Returning false from `push` is just to advise that the buffer is building up, it's up to the consuming code to act on that advice but I don't think it has any impact on the buffering. You don't need to `pause` the stream since you are in flow mode responding to `data` events. If you want to respond to the back pressure, you need to stop pushing and start listening for the `drain` event of the stream which signals that the buffer is clear again.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet as how to do that?